# Google Dagger com.android.support:support-v4 dependency versions

Tags: android, dagger-2

In an app compiling against Api 23 (6.0), I get a warning in the build.gradle file that "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification" and that versions 24.2.0 & 23.1.1 were found.

My com.android.support dependencies all specify 23.1.1 but running:

```
gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

shows that these are all upgraded to 24.2.0.

The only exception to this is

```
com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.9
```

which appears to be dependent on

```
com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0
```

Excerpts from gradlew dependency report:

```
+--- project :AppCommon
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 24.2.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0
|    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.0
|    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:24.2.0
|    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0 (*)
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:24.2.0
|    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:24.2.0
|    |              +--- com.android.support:support-compat:24.2.0 (*)
|    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:24.2.0 (*)
|    |              +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:24.2.0 (*)
|    |              \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:24.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 24.2.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:design:23.1.1
|    |    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1 -> 24.2.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 24.2.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 -> 24.2.0 (*)




|    \--- com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.9
|         +--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9 (*)
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0
```

How can I resolve this dependency clash other than by changing compiling against api 24 (and changing all my com.android.support versions to 24.2.0)?

Answer (score 0):

Update Gradle plugin to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Change the gradle compile sdk version, buildtool version and target sdk version to a updated one.

For sample,

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
targetSdkVersion 25
```

And change the gradle dependency to the same version of builtoolversion

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-fragment:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
```

You must use the dagger dependency as

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
```

instead of

```
com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.9
com.google.dagger:dagger:2.9
```

Comment: Thanks, but the main users of the app are on Android 6.0 so I would like to compile against  API 23